# How to not show context menu for multi selection in Eclipse Plugin Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a context menu for an Eclipse plugin. I need to show the context popup menu only if the user selects a single file. Currently, I am able to show the context menu for multi selection of folders in the Project Explorer. The requirement is to disable or hide the context menu for multi selection of Folders.
I cannot use the legacy context popup menu "" as it has been deprecated in Eclipse.

I've provided a snippet of my plugin.xml.

```xml
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category name="My Category" id="mycategory.id" />
      <command name="Drop it here" categoryId="mycategory.id" id="myCmd1" />
   </extension>
   
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler commandId="myCmd1" class="com.toyer.FirstHandler" />
   </extension>
   
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
         <command commandId="myCmd1" icon="icons/pino16.png">
            <visibleWhen>
               <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                  <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" />
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   
</plugin>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count` to limit the selection to 1

Something like:

```xml
<with variable="selection">
   <count value="1"/>
   <iterate>
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
   </iterate>
</with>
```

Comment: Thank you greg-449 Sir, I know you are the best in Eclipse.